# Spring boot Prometheus , micrometer not able to publish data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am using micrometer to publish some event

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Metrics; 

/**
 *
 * @param eventName : event name to publish
 */
public static void recordEvent(String eventName){
    Metrics.counter(eventName).increment();
}
```

and calling it from my application class like this

```
 metricsCollector.recordEvent("metric name");
```

and mapping prometheus end point like this in properties file

```
endpoints.prometheus.path=metrics
```

but when i go to the http://localhost:8082/metrics i am not able to see the event

I assumed it to be some problem with the registry and tried to add registry like this

```
 Metrics.addRegistry(new CompositeMeterRegistry());
```

but it also didn't worked out.

```
Spring boot version : 1.5.9
Java version 1.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.x doesn't have built-in support for micrometer.  That's in Spring boot 2.x.  For custom metrics in Spring Boot 1.x see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-enabling

Comment: But i see currently the http://localhost:8082/prometheus link is getting other data, but my counters are not getting reflected, if i do something like this    
                Counter eventCounter = Metrics.counter(eventName);
        eventCounter.increment();
        log.info("Counter called second"+eventCounter.count());  it prints the counter value  correctly